Female physiology before and after Eve's sin (Eruvin 100b)
The Gemmorah in Eruvin 100b lists various physiological and Halachic outcomes of the Curse of Eve (Gen 3.16) :

"... Rav Yitzḥak bar Avdimi says: Eve was cursed with ten curses... [the Gemmorah lists seven]
... a baraita teaches three additional curses:
she grows her hair long like Lilit, a demon;
she sits and urinates, like an animal;
and serves as a pillow for her husband during relations."

Regarding the second curse in this list, I understand that Eve's physiology was somehow different before the sin (or maybe they didn't engage in bodily functions at all?).
Does anyone address this observation?

This follows the paradigm already established from Bereshit 1:14-19. That only in regard to external expression in this material world, the wife has 4 limbs more than her husband. He has 248 and she has 252. In reality, they are equal, meaning 250 each. That 250 is נר, like it states, “the two great sources of light”. Adam and Chava merely continue the already established paradigm.

You should also reflect about the nature of the “curses” enumerated. “Sitting” while urinating is not really what is observed. Female mammals squat. Male mammals urinate upright or lifting their leg like a dog. The reference to “serving as a cushion” is referring to the way most mammals breed, meaning from behind. The male mounts from behind and the female often crouches, like with lions. Humans, when breeding are face-to-face. What this is referring to is evolving beyond animal to human. Chava was initially seduced by the Nachash, an animal or “ Wildman”.

@YaacovDeane This is very insightful but I fail to see how it relates to the question. Eve was cursed to urinate the way animals do. Does it mean that previously her anatomy was different?

It would seem to be relating to behavior more than physical anatomy. In other words, it was a step backward in an evolutionary sense. If you think about it, a change and diminishment in condition is compared with death, like when a wealthy individual becomes poor. That is also considered a kind of spiritual death.

@YaacovDeane I agree, but before we dive into esoteric interpretations, I'd like to understand mere physiology - how it was planned. Was Eve designed to urinate standing humanly like Adam?

Since she was part of the original design of the first in the species, meaning Adam Kadmon, it suggests yes. But I was just learning something from Ramchal in Adir B’Marom, that suggests perhaps not. He mentions that when G-d first established the paradigm of male & female in Humans, they arose in potential from אמא (עיל׳). That means from G-d’s name צלמו which is transcends the division.

To put this into a context that you might appreciate, this would relate to the female individual referred to as "Mitochondrial Eve" meaning אמא (עיל׳). Chronologically, approximately 150,000 years ago. Like Torah explains, there were proto human precursors (10 groups globally) prior to this female. She gave birth to a son and daughter (Adam and Chava). Here's a link for the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve
